# Check input in if else statement not working in python

Tags: python, if-statement, input

I am wondering what I'm doing wrong. I want the following if/else statement to print "The number is 4." when 4 is entered in the input. But after entering 4, it always says "Number is not 4." It is in python. Thanks in advance

```
if sample_number == 4:
    print("The number is 4")
else:
    print("Number is not 4.")
```

Comment: Most likely `sample_number` is the string `4` and not the number 4. Try like this: int(sample_number).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont have a lot of context but it's most likely a string so just try converting it like this:

```
sample_number = int(sample_number)
if sample_number == 4:
    print("The number is 4")
else:
    print("Number is not 4.")
```

Answer (score 1):

The input type is a string so 4 != "4"

**This will work:**

```
if sample_number == "4":
    print("The number is 4")
else:
    print("Number is not 4.")
```